# How far away can you mine blocks while standing in one place?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

To my surprise, I could not find this by googling, but what is the arm reach of the player? As in, how far can you mine blocks while standing in one place?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As of Minecraft 1.0, the reach distance [seems to have changed](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/mn4sy/2_things_i_havent_seen_posted_on_reddit_since_the/). It appears to be 4 metres (blocks) in SSP (survival single player), and 5 meters in multiplayer (most likely to compensate for the lag, making combat and block placement easier).

---

In my testing, when mining directly in front of your character (at head level) and when right against the block you are mining, you can mine **four blocks** ahead of your player. (I was right against the red wool block, and I couldn't reach the cyan block at the end.)

[image: Rainbow blocks!]
[image: Third person view.]

---

To further research the reach of the character, I experimented to see how far I could reach on the green block while still being able to mine it. I was able to reach about two-fifths on the block before I couldn't mine it anymore. (My cursor is on the very furthest point that I could still mine the block.)

[image: Two-fifths by my estimation at least.]

Because calculating his reach based on *exactly* where his arm is relative to the physics engine and how far *exactly* I reached on the green block would be difficult, I'm going to estimate that he reaches **approximately 3.6 meters**.

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't tell me if the mining distance is just barely over 3 or just under 4.

Comment: Good point. I'll do a little more research.

Comment: I did my own experiment with this some time ago and came up with the same result.  Also: 1) placing blocks has the same range, and 2) using a tool doesn't extend your range.

Comment: If you could reach 2/5ths of the blocks, wouldn't that mean his reach is 3.*4*?

Comment: Since arm level is somewhere around 1.5 blocks above ground level, the distance would be the diagonal of a rectangle, where `x` equals `~3.4`, and `y` equals the distance between the arm and the top of the rainbow blocks.

Comment: @kevinY Wanna update this answer now that Minecraft has officially released?

Comment: @Arkive Good idea.

Comment: I am 90% sure that reach has increased to 5 blocks somewhere between 1.0 and 1.8. Could you update the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you play Pocket Edition, like I do, its an average of 6 blocks (5.37 metres). In Xbox or PC, its 4 or 5 blocks (3.58 to 4.475 metres) Hope this answer helps!

Comment: Where did you get the idea 1 block != 1 meter?

Comment: He didn't say that. But blocks, unlike distance, have full number coordinates.

Comment: @Penguin At the time this question was posted, there was no Java/Bedrock split and we had one main [minecraft] tag. Plus, this answer could be useful to users finding this question through Google, regardless of how it is tagged. There was always going to be some overlap - not every question can or should be split cleanly down the middle.

Comment: @Robotnik okay, didnt realize timestamp, nvm that flag then, but the second part [goes against this ("unofficial") agreement](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15397/258509). Even though that's about questions the reverse would apply for answers

Comment: @Penguin It might be worth bringing this to meta ("Should old answers from before the minecraft tag split be deleted?") - but in general I'm very wary when deleting answers that help the people who are finding the questions through Google. We already allow different answers for people playing games on different platforms, I don't see why game versions should be any different.