# How many blocks can you reach(break) without moving?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the maximum number of blocks can you reach(break) without moving at all? (Assume that there are no moving part/command blocks in the world)

Comment: does falling because you mined the block under your feet count as moving?

Comment: @Arperum No, I will clarify that in the question now. (Done)

Comment: You forgot to specify "no infinite cobblestone generators". If they're allowed, 56154.

Comment: Tens of thousands... if you have a bow and arrow.

Comment: @Bizorke Clever. Care to determine exact value?

Comment: No way you'll have to ask that in a separate question :P. Obviously this is not what you meant here, I'm just being a smart ass. But even though you've added the qualifier "break" to the question, I would argue the answer is bounded only by the number of blocks loaded in memory if you allow redstone/TNT reactions to count as reaching/breaking a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just did an experiment to find out.

###Testing Methodology
0. Generate creative superflat world full of glass. [Preset](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Superflat#Preset_code_format) used: `3;256*minecraft:glass;127;`
0. Disable <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys.
0. Teleport the player to according location. (See the results)
0. Break all reachable blocks. Used [turbo click](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/28516-turbo-mode/) AutoHotkey script to accelerate the process.
0. Execute `/fill ~-9 ~-9 ~-9 ~9 ~9 ~9 stained_glass 0 keep` to count the blocks broken in creative mode.

###Results

- When normally "standing" on the center of block(`/tp X.5, Y.0, Z.5`): 767 blocks.
- When the player's eye is exactly at the corner of the block(`/tp X.0, Y.38, Z.0`): 720 blocks. (Which is divisible by 2^3=8)

Comment: Uhm, I play this game for quite a long time, but I ever though that you have bigger reach in creative than in survival.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík It was changed quite a few versions ago.

Answer (score 1):

It is 4 blocks in **single player survival** and 5 blocks in **multiplayer survival**. Also, this question may be a duplicate :([How far away can you mine blocks while standing in one place?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27395/how-far-away-can-you-mine-blocks-while-standing-in-one-place))

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity but my question allowed looking around. So obviously much more than 5 blocks.